# Frog/toad species?

Tags: animal-identification, frogs

Does anyone know what this toad is, I used to see them a ton when I was younger and I saw two today while attending to lawn care.

Does anyone know the species, found in Nebraska; it’s about 1 inch long, it is july

[image: Frog or toad with spotted markings]